# Can I get rid of postfix if i am not sending email from server?

Tags: linux, postfix

I am not a sysadmin, just managing a a dedicated server, I get a high load due to Postfix, i shut it down it was the only way to not hang the server.

Comment: If you get a high load due to postfix something pretty bad is going on on your dedicated server, such as it has been compromised and is sending spam.

Comment: you are right, in my case, /dev/root was full due to bad logging file management. I suppose Postfix had dificulties for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above, but I would just set up your server so the postfix service isn't started. (rc.conf on FreeBSD for example). The idea here is postfix and a mail server in general is a huge amount of work to set up. I wouldn't start uninstalling files. You would probably want to make sure none of the email related programs are started. That would be postfix, dovecot, spamd, amavisd-new and probably a few others. Sendmail should already be disabled.

So you would change the config file for the services and also kill them by hand, or just change the config file and boot. You didn't mention the OS, so I cant comment more.

Comment: Hi, it's centos 6.thanks for the input.